# PayPal Subscription Failed Payment Webhook flow

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-webhooks

i was wondering what webhook is sent when a subscription payment fails?. I wish to downgrade a user on my website if a payment isn't made/fails. but im unsure if the 'Billing.Subscription.Cancelled or Billing.Subscription.Suspended is sent.' I have the "max_fail_attempts": "1".
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Paypal apis & documents are suck. you can check this link

https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Webhooks-REST-APIs/regarding-webhook-of-billing-agreement/td-p/1450631

I never see this callback sent, now i give up these webhooks and try IPN instead, hope it works.

there is another link maybe help, in 2015 guys said webhooks supports for recurring payment is in progress, I think it still in progress now.
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/242

Comment: IPN works fine, I remove all webhooks and setup IPN, you can check this link:      https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

Comment: Thankyou, the first link help a lot!